# Remove USB Host Controller driver from Linux

Tags: linux-device-driver

Can you please let me know how do i disable/remove the USB Host Controller driver from the kernel. Is there a way I can unhook the usb driver module from the kernel.

Linux 2.6.24.7-r1116 / Fedora

Comment: You'll need to recompile your kernel to do this.  Is there any reason you need this?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: @Paul. U mean the question/answer is already available on superuser.com..I could not find any reference, can you please point me if there is such a reference..

Comment: no, StackOverflow is for programming questions - superuser.com is for questions about hardware and software, such as yours. It will probably get moved to superuser.com when it has enough close votes.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo lsmod | grep ohci
sudo lsmod | grep ehci
```

If these commands show nothing - then your host controller drivers are compilled into the kernel. Otherwise rmmod all modules, that my commands show.

This is a programmer question. I've used this techinque while debugging hotplug of my USB device in my device driver.